# android ListView subitem database

Tags: android, database, eclipse, listview

I'm making an application with a database of courses (of school) that the user is participating in. I want to display those courses in a list (im using listview) and use also the subitem (extra information of that course) of the listitems. I found a tutorial (http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) that displays a list like I want but it uses a class to store the data in instead of a database. So the tutorial uses an arraylist of objects of that class. It would be a detour though if i had to put my information from my database into a class to put it in the list.

Does anyone have a clue how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a beter way. By using a simple adapter and putting the values of the cursor in a hashmap in a arraylist. Found the idea from this site: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/01/03/android-simple-listview-using-simpleadapter/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perfect tutorial for what you need. It shows you how to create a simple SQLite database and then populate a listview using the database.
[SQLite Database creation and Listview Population Tutorial](http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/android-using-the-sqlite-database-with-listview/)